# i can not open a google maps in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a method called **mapsample()**, this method return a Google maps but dont working in my app.
If i call the method in my vist **Home** it work.
this method it's in **ListPage**.

What am I doing wrong?

> Home

```
body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/coffee_bg.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: ListPage()
        ),
      ));
```

> mapsample() Method

```
mapsample() {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );
  return Container(child: GoogleMap(
    mapType: MapType.hybrid,
    initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
      _controller.complete(controller);
    },
  ));
}
```

> ListPage

```
children: <Widget>[
                                    ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                        topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
                                        topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
                                      ),
                                      child: Image.network(ad.data.toString(),
                                        width: 300,
                                        height: 150,
                                        fit:BoxFit.fill  

                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    ListTile(
                                      title: Text("Reportado por:"+snapshot.data[index].data["nombre"].toString()+" "+snapshot.data[index].data["apellidos"].toString()),
                                      subtitle: Text("Origen de la fuga:"+snapshot.data[index].data["colonia"].toString()),
                                    ),
                                     FlatButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.map),
              label: Text('ver ubicación'),
              onPressed:() => mapsample()
                                    
                                     )],
```

Comment: Method `onPressed` is not expecting a Widget as result. Returning the map widget from `onPressed` callback is not going to work.  How are you showing the map in the home?

Comment: I put the method in Home and then call it,I only did it to test if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make the return type of mapsample() to "Widget" to return the widget GoogleMaps.

Now you can create a widget variable, say "child" outside the function anywhere. And inside the onPressed method call setState and use that to return mapsample() into this child Widget variable created.

If I understood your code right, this should work I believe.